# Is it possible to pause/resume/manipulate a swiffyobject from JS?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, google-swiffy

There seems to be little support or discussion around regarding Google Swiffy (http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/).

Is it possible to effectively pause/resume/manipulate a swiffyobject from JS?

Using standard Google output, I noticed the swiffyobject could be found in console with a few properties; notably frameRate. Could this property be manipulated for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having un-minified the runtime.js - it was possible to achieve the behaviour I wanted.

On line 3312 (unminified - jsbeautifier.org)

```
M.start = function (arg) {
this.T[Qa]();
if(arg){
this.cb.start(arg)
}else{
this.cb.start()
}
};
```

And on line 3823:

```
M.start = function(arg)  {

    if(arg){
        console.log(arg);
        window.clearInterval(window.pauseAnimation)

    }else{
        window.pauseAnimation = window.setInterval(Ob(this.ne, this), 40 );
        if (!this.ie) this.ie = !0, this.ne(), window.pauseAnimation

    }     

};
```

Then using console, it is possible to pause/resume your animation using:

```
stage.start(true) // PAUSE the animation.
stage.start() // RESUME the animation.
```

Answer (score 6):

For the latest Swiffy release (Swiffy runtime version 5.2 https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js) I did this.

1.Use jsbeautifier.org as mentioned in samb's post.

2.Find the function containing *.start()*. In my case...

```
db(N, function () {
    var a = this.Dg;
    this.ck(function () {
        a.start()
    })
});
db(Yj[I], Yj[I].start);
```

3.Duplicate this function with a different name, and replace *start()* with *stop()*

```
myNewFunction(N, function () {
    var a = this.Dg;
    this.ck(function () {
        a.stop()
    })
});
myNewFunction(Yj[I], Yj[I].stop);
```

4.Find the declaration of the function containing *.start()*. In my case *db*.

```
function db(a, b) {
    return a.start = b
}
```

5.Duplicate this function and call it the same as the new function you created with *stop()* in and replace *start* with *stop*. In my case *myNewFunction*.

```
function myNewFunction(a, b) {
    return a.stop = b
}
```

That's it.

Now you can call my *anim.stop();*

e.g.

```
//create anim
var anim = {swiffy code};
var myAnim = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('animContainer'), anim);
myAnim.start();

//some button click
myButton.on('click',function(){
  myAnim.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for my english I'm french;)
I was looking for a solution to be able to properly handle animation Swiffy.
Since the new version (5.0) google code has changed and I can no longer maniupler animation with small hacks found on the net ...
For cons, I coded force to find a solution .. which seems to me very simple and clean .. (without touching the source Swiffy!)
In fact any part of this post : [swiffy / javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213225/get-a-response-from-javascript-in-a-googles-swiffy-content-flash-converted-to)

Can be recovered with flashvars Swiffy (in as2 and as3 it should work too ..)

the side javascript can do this kind of things:

```
function playMovie(){
    stage.setFlashVars('myresponse=play');
    return false;
  }
  function stopMovie(){
    stage.setFlashVars('myresponse=pause');
    return false;
  }
```

and the side of the flash in a function enterFrame ... :

```
_root.onEnterFrame = function(){
switch(_level0.myresponse){
    case 'play':
        _root.play();
        break;

    case 'pause':
        _root.stop();
        break;

    default :
        break;
}
_level0.myresponse = undefined;
 }
```

and that's it!
To you organize the methods you want but .. it works;)
Must retake the undefined variable if you want to reuse it later ;)

Comment: Add a swiffy tag on this to get more relevant traffic.