# get a response from javascript in a google's swiffy content? (flash converted to html5)

Tags: actionscript-2, google-swiffy

I am trying to play with google's swiffy to convert as2 content into html5.

so far it has been amazing.

using getURL, I can make javascript calls.

But, will I be able to get sort of response from a server or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can call `stage.setFlashVars('response=10');` from the JavaScript after which `_level0.response` should be set in AS2. But `getURL` returns before `_level0.response` is set. So a you should wait a little bit with `setTimeout` or `onEnterFrame`.

Comment: hi have you tried that before? According to Google  stage.setFlashVars can only be called before stage.start(); What i guess is we cannot keep setting flash vars when the stage has already started. source:http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/faq.html

Comment: I edited my answer, but it probably was rejected. So I have put an example (including the source-fla) [here](http://www.ronaldliauw.nl/stackoverflow/dunforget/)

Comment: Yesterday I finished [this](http://www.ronaldliauw.nl/nudn/woordzoeker/). The words from the 'woordzoeker'-games and the url's from the sounds are controlled by xml-files. Works great in Chrome but less in Firefox and Safari. When SVG is available I use swiffy otherwise flash but it should be the other way around. First flash then swiffy.

Comment: I accidently replaced the 'woordzoeker'-games by a Flash CreatJs-version of the game. I like the fact that games exported with the CreateJs-plugin also can work on the iPad and iPod as CreatJs targets canvas instead of svg.